# In IDA 5, is there a way to rename a stack variable mid-function

Tags: ida, disassembly, stack-variables

I am reverse engineering a program using IDA Pro Free 5. In one of the functions, the compiler has reused the stack space of one of the passed in arguments as a local variable of a different type, but the same size.

Is there a way to rename a stack variable part of the way through a function? At the moment, I'm using a manual operand, but its not optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not even possible in IDA 6.9 yet, and definitely not possible in IDA 5.

When encountering such cases (which are quite frequent with certain compilers), I often find it the easiest to give such variables a name that denotes them as having two different purposes shared on the same stack address.

Comment: Well, that's a pain. I was thinking of working around with SP diff, but that's messier.
I guess I could use your naming and a union to show which context is being used.